# Scanning array with sequencial index after double recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'am trying to have a normal increment index after a double recursive function call. The problem is my index isn't incremented with one every call, and I cannot compare my array with BST tree to check if my input was preord or not. It works just with one recursive call. This my code:

```
int checkPreord(struct BST *root,int *v, int index)
{

  if(!root)
  {   
   return 1;
  }

  if(v[index]!=root->data){
    printf("%d %d\n",v[index],root->data);
   return 0;    
  }

  checkPreord(root->left,v,index+1);

  checkPreord(root->right,v,index+1);
}
```

Comment: If `root` is not a null pointer and `v[index]!=root->data` is false, what do you return then?

Comment: root will become NULL as soon as the tree is all scanned.

Comment: You declare that the `checkPreorder` function will return an `int` Value, and yet there is a path through the function where you *don't* return anything. If you ever want to check the returned value then that will lead to *undefined behavior*. You need to explicitly have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution using a vector doing a push_back every function call, this is the complete program to check a preorder input.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct BST{
     struct BST *left;
     struct BST *right;
     int data;

    };

   void insert(struct BST **root,int val)
   {
     if(*root==NULL)
     {
      struct BST *tmp;
      tmp=(struct BST*)malloc(sizeof(struct BST));
      tmp->data = val;
      tmp->left= tmp->right= NULL;
      *root=tmp;
      return;
     }

     if(val < (*root)->data)
       insert(&(*root)->left,val);
     else
       insert(&(*root)->right,val);

      return;

   }

 void checkPreord(struct BST *root, vector<int> &v2)
 {

   if(!root)
     return;

   v2.push_back(root->data);

  checkPreord(root->left,v2);
  checkPreord(root->right,v2);


 }  

 void deleteTree(struct BST* node)  
 {  
    if (node == NULL) return;  

   deleteTree(node->left);  
   deleteTree(node->right);  
   free(node);  
 }  


 int main()
 {
   int ntests;

   scanf("%d",&ntests);
   while(ntests--)
   {
    struct BST *root=NULL;
    int size;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    vector<int>v;
    vector<int>v2;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        int val;
        scanf("%d",&val);
        v.push_back(val);
        insert(&root,v[i]);

    }

    checkPreord(root,v2);
    deleteTree(root);
    if(v==v2)
     printf("1\n");
    else
     printf("0\n");



  }
 return 0;
}
```